# Windows installation is stuck at initial loading screen

Tags: windows-7, windows, virtualbox, virtual-machine, virtualization

My Windows installation on VirtualBox is stuck on the initial setup screen. I checked that virtualization is enabled and the ISO image works fine in Hyper-V VMs on the same machine. I googled some logs and also checked YouTube, but nothing seems to work.

[image: stuck window]

Windows 7 64-bit - 2GB of RAM - 15 GB of disk space

After around 20 minutes the VM window has only a mouse pointer with a black background.

Comment: Can you add some more info regarding the virtual box? How much ram did you alot to it? What version of windows? Given the update, it might just have been given insufficient ram... i.e. it might not be stuck, just really really slow.

Comment: No i'm sure i did everything right + it works fine in hyper-v with the same props

Comment: Is your host pc 64bit? Does your virtual box support 64 bit?

Comment: Can you run 2 different VM software's on the same PC?

Comment: yes my OS it is 64 bit

Comment: and yes you can run 2 different VM software

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay bois apparently windows 10 has something stupid called Device Guard or Credential Guard you need to disable it ( solution found in the second page of google search BTW ).